# Merging directories and joining inner files with bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash4

I have bunch of directories following this structure:

```
\directories\
 |---\directory1\
 |      |---file1.txt
 |      |---file2.txt
 |
 |---\directory2\
 |      |---file1.txt
 |      |---file3.txt
 |
 |---\directory3\
 |      |---file4.txt
 |      |---file2.txt
```

I want to merge the directories and files so it ends up like this:

```
\directories\
 |---\directory1\
 |      |---file1.txt
 |      |---file2.txt
 |
 |---\directory2\
 |      |---file1.txt
 |      |---file3.txt
 |
 |---\directory3\
 |      |---file4.txt
 |      |---file2.txt
 |
 |---\mergeddata\
 |      |---file1.txt (from dir1 and dir2)
 |      |---file2.txt (from dir1 and dir4)
 |      |---file3.txt (from dir2)
 |      |---file4.txt (from dir3)
```

I am awful with bash and been trying quite a few things but... not getting any good results.

Looking forward to some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say how you want the files merged, or in what order.  I will guess "concatenated, with directory1 appearing before diretory2, and directory2 before directory3"?

The following script shows a straightforward way to do this, without relying on fancy substitutions:

```
cd directories
mkdir mergeddata
for I in directory1 directory2 directory3 ; do   # replace with your actual directory list
    for F in "$I"/* ; do
        B=$(basename "$F")
        cat "$F" >> "mergeddata/$B"
    done
done
```

**Edit:** I added some quotes, in case any of your filenames end up with space characters or other inconvenient white space.

Comment: Why do you use `cat` instead of `cp` to copy the file content?

Comment: @GearoidMurphy:  Because the original question asked to merge files with like names.  Notice that I'm also using the `>>` append operator to append to the target file as opposed to overwriting it.

Comment: +1 Useful use of cat! You can use `for I in */; do` to iterated over the subdirectories of "directories"

Comment: @glennjackman:  Doing `for I in */` would work if the target directory were not in the current directory.  But in this example, `mergeddata` is in the same directory as `directory1`, `directory2` and `directory3`.  The `for` loop would do surprising things once `I` becomes `mergeddata`.

Comment: In that case, since we're tagged [tag:bash], `shopt -s extglob; for I in !(mergedata)/`